# copying files from web using urllib.request.urlretrieve, but nothing is pasted

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to copy files from a website and locally save them, using the following codes. But my local driver shows the saved files are empty (i.e., each excel file is created but contains 1 KB memory). Any comments about why this is not working?

```
import urllib.request
import pathlib

folder_euronext = "C:/myfolder/"
url_euronext = "https://live.euronext.com/sites/default/files/statistics/factbook/yearly/"
for i in range(2013,2020):
    filename = "euronext_fact_book_"+str(i)+".xls" if i <= 2016 else "euronext_fact_book_"+str(i)+".xlsx"
    print(url_euronext+filename)
    if pathlib.Path(folder_euronext+filename).exists():
        print(filename,"exists...")
    else: 
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_euronext+filename, folder_euronext+filename)
        print("Copying and pasting",filename)
```

Comment: well if you open the saved files in a text editor, then you'd have noticed that the contents are `<html><head><title>Request Rejected</title></head><body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br><br>Your support ID is: 7846526776193841905</body></html>` indicating that the website does not like your URLs.

Comment: The URLs seem to work when downloading via CURL so I'd look at perhaps adding a user-agent header to your GET request.

Comment: Justin, thanks for your quick comment, but I have little idea what are the CURL and user-agent header. Can you tell me how/which part of my code should revised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below. You'll need to install [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

```
import requests
import pathlib
import time

headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36c'}

folder_euronext = pathlib.Path(".")

url_euronext = "https://live.euronext.com/sites/default/files/statistics/factbook/yearly/"
for i in range(2013,2020):
    filename = "euronext_fact_book_"+str(i)+".xls" if i <= 2016 else "euronext_fact_book_"+str(i)+".xlsx"
    print(url_euronext+filename)
    target = folder_euronext / filename
    if pathlib.Path(target).exists():
        print(filename,"exists...")
    else: 
        resp = requests.get(url_euronext+filename, headers=headers)
        with open(target, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(resp.content)

        print("Copying and pasting",filename)
        
    time.sleep(2.0)
```

Comment: Thanks millions! I will check the headers option of requests.get.